# Updates Stored Proc string or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've seen a few variations to this question all over but haven't found an answer that i can use yet! I have a stored procedure that updates a table, The table def is VARCHAR(MAX) for each column and the stored procedure inserts box standard text no more than 100 characters. but its throwing a

> string or binary data would be truncated

Am i missing something obvious

Stored Proc is :

```
insert tblPara
(
    Para1
  , Para2
  , Para3
)
values
(
@Para1 ,
@Para2 ,
@Para3
```

and the value's are just text fields that get entered into it. tbl PARA is set to VARCHAR(MAX) on each col

Comment: Can you post the code of the stored procedure? (parameter declaration most importantly). And the `EXEC` or `sp_executesql` line with which you are calling the stored procedure?

Comment: Have you triggers on your table?

Comment: no triggers or anything, added stored proc. its a very very basic procedure.

Comment: @Gavlaaa This can't be the code of the stored procedure. Please post the exact code and the declaration of parameters `@Para1`, `@Para2`, `@Para3`. Also, post the command with which you call the stored procedure and the parameters you pass when you get this error (if you want us to give you an answer and a solution)

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the field is  not big enough to hold the data that you are trying to insert. It is obvious that that you have set your field to a size that is smaller than the size of the data that you are trying to insert. Check your stored procedure and increase the size of that field.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the parameters are not the right size. YOu didn;t show us how you deifned them, so it is hard to say.

However, you do know it is horrible practice to use varchar(max) for all the fields in a table right? It precludes the efficient use of indexing which is critical to database performance. If this is some sort of staging table, that's not a problem, but do not use this design in a prodcution table.